# Correct polynomial regression formula using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am performing multiple polynomial regression using sklearn. What I cannot understand is how can I get the full polynomial formula? Is the order in printed `coef_` correct? I am trying to put together a correct regression equation but nothing works.

I have a code here where I get the predicted values, coefficients and intercept.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

Y = df['Y']
X = df[['X1', 'X2']]

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)
poly.fit(X_poly, Y)

lin2 = LinearRegression()
model = lin2.fit(X_poly, Y)
y_pred = model_3.predict(X_poly)

print(y_pred)

print('Regression coefficients: ', model.coef_)
print('Intercept: ', model_3.intercept_)

Regression coefficients: [0.0 -3.9407245056806457 63.36152983871869 -0.0073134316780316105 0.28728821270355437 -1.8955885488237727 -317.773937549386]
Intercept:  40.587981548779965
```

Let's say that X1 = 167.8 and X2 = 22.348595, after the regression the predicted value is 361.67, but none of the version of equation is not giving the result of  361.67.

I find that `coef_` prints `[1, a, b, c, a^2, b^2, c^2, ab, bc, ca]`, so in this case `[1, a, b, a^2, b^2, ab]`, but I am not sure that the sequence here is correct. I am not getting  361.67, but 370.56 with this:

```
y =  0.0 + -3.94 * X1 +  63.36  * X2 + -0.007  * X1^2 +  0.2872  * X1 * X2 +  -1.895  *  X2^2 + -317.77
```

Comment: I was able to get your previous value before you edited of 361, is the desired value now 350.41? I got 361 simply by putting in the full decimals into the equation. Are the X1 and X2 you provide full decimals?

Comment: Sorry, predicted value is 361.67. You used the same equation? Cause with this y =  0.0 + -3.94 * 167 +  63.36  * 22 + -0.007  * 167**2 +  0.2872  * 167 * 22 +  -1.895  *  22**2 + -317.77 I get 360.97320000000013, but it's not  361.67, why?

Comment: Is 361.67832067451957 predicted? You must put in all decimal places: y =  0.0 + -3.9407245056806457 * X1 +  63.36152983871869  * X2 + -0.0073134316780316105 * X1^2 +  0.28728821270355437  * X1 * X2 +  -1.8955885488237727 *  X2^2 -317.773937549386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is anything wrong with formula or the order, it is just that rounding the decimals will make a difference from your prediction by a more significant amount than you expected.

If you put in all decimal places in the regression coefficients in the order you originally have, you will get the correct predicted value of 361.67 I believe.

Please let me know if there is anything wrong or if I misinterpreted the issue.

For example:

```
X1 = 167.8
X2 = 22.348595

y =  0.0 + -3.9407245056806457 * X1 +  63.36152983871869  * X2 + -0.0073134316780316105 * X1**2 +  0.28728821270355437  * X1 * X2 +  -1.8955885488237727 *  X2**2 -317.773937549386


print(y)
```

Output:

```
361.67832067451957
```